# Selecting a specific number of results from columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a larger data source where I'm looking to gather the User IDs (Column 'A') for a specific group of people based on the value in column 'B' and so I have created a new dataframe with the info that I need using:

```
df2 = df1[df1['B'].isin([8,9,9.5,10,11])]
```

Now I need to get the the first 40 values from col 'A' for value 8 in col 'B' and then the first 32 values from col 'A' for value 9 etc. etc. which i can do because my data is already sorted by the most relevant users - I just need to pick out X amount of them per the value in col 'B'

I want the output of that to be in this format ideally:

```
 A   B 
ID1  8
ID2  8
. . 
ID41 9 
ID42 9
```

I thought of using this for example

`df2[(df2['B']== 8)][0:40]`

but then i have to slice the dataframe X times to get all the User IDs for the values I need and there must be a quick way to specify the number of values from each column without slicing for each value in col 'B'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need build the condition map `dict`, then just do `groupby` with `head`

```
d = {8:40,9:32}

out = df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x : x.head(d[x['B'].iloc[0]])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or try with `cumcount`

```
out = df[df.groupby('B').cumcount() < df.B.map(d)]
```

Comment: You are a legend sir - the first suggestion didn't work for me but i wanted to ask about the second part of the cumcount solution - can you explain why you used the < operator and the '.map' function

Comment: @kasje cumcount is cumulative count how many row from 0 to n-1 per group , since we know how many row we would like to get per group , just need the cumcount number right before the limit